# python tuple returns datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime

**The Problem:**

Whenever I get the result of the following query:

```
"SELECT email, url, `timestamp` FROM `transaction` WHERE `email` != '' AND `timestamp` >= \'" + dateonlystring + "\' AND `timestamp` < DATE(DATE_ADD(\'" + dateonlystring + "\', INTERVAL 1 DAY))"
```

This comes up:

('sampleemail@yahoo.com', 'http://sample.url.com', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 25, 10, 11, 19))

Why is it a datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 25, 10, 11, 19))?

And how can I turn that into this:

sampleemail@yahoo.com~http://sample.url.com~2015-02-25 10:11:19

**My Code / What I Tried:**

```
#Date
#datestamp = datetime.strptime('2015-02-25 00:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datestamp = datetime.now()
dateonlystring = str(datestamp.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
datetimestring = str(datestamp.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))

#Dunchangeme:
#Query:
q_getstuff = "SELECT email, url, `timestamp` FROM `transaction` WHERE `email` != '' AND `timestamp` >= \'" + dateonlystring + "\' AND `timestamp` < DATE(DATE_ADD(\'" + dateonlystring + "\', INTERVAL 1 DAY))"

try:
    con = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, database)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(q_getstuff)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    for row in result:
        tuplecrap = str(row).replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('\'', '').replace(', ', '~')
        print tuplecrap
```

Of note is that the commented first `datestamp` is there if the user intends to go to a specific date (as opposed to only now).

The easiest way would be to simply get rid of the parenthesis and commas, as I did above, but that doesn't solve the problem without going into complex regex solutions, and I'm pretty sure it's not the right way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Converting the tuple to a string and manipulating it is definitely not the "easiest way". You seem to be aware of the `strftime` function, why not use that?

Comment: what is `mdb`? Why do you use the string formatting instead of parameterized queries? Normally, you should just pass `datetime` (and preferably --  *timezone-aware* datetime objects) and the driver should serialize to the format that the sql engine understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tuples with 3 items in each result row, just unpack it:

```
for row in result:
    email, url, date = row
    # here you can format date as you want
```

Comment: Wow. I did not know you could do this.