# psycopg2 selecting timestamp returns datetime.datetime wrapped in tuple, how to unpack?

Tags: python, datetime, tuples, psycopg2

I have created a table:

```
 cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE articles (title varchar PRIMARY KEY, pubDate timestamp with time zone);")
```

I inserted a timestamp like this:

```
timestamp = date_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO articles VALUES (%s, %s)", 
              (title, timestamp))
```

When I run a SELECT statement to retrieve the timestamps, it returns tuples instead:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT pubDate FROM articles")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

This is the returned row:

```
(datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 47, 4, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=660, name=None)),)
```

How can I retrieve the datetime object directly?

I've looked up a few other related questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184465/how-to-cast-date-to-string-in-psycopg2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724968/python-tuple-returns-datetime-datetime)) but can't seem to find the answer. Probably overlooking something simple here but any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python's `datetime` objects are automatically [adapted](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation) into SQL by `psycopg2`, you don't need to stringify them:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO articles VALUES (%s, %s)", 
               (title, datetime_obj))
```

To read the rows returned by a `SELECT` you can use the cursor as an iterator, unpacking the row tuples as needed:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT pubDate FROM articles")

for pub_date, in cursor:  # note the comma after `pub_date`
    print(pub_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

But it fixed it when I tried the following: print(row[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")). I simply had to unpack the tuple.... Thanks for clearing some things up though :)

Comment: @freefall: I've updated the code to address the actual problem.

Comment: Ah didn't know you could loop through tuples like that, that simplifies it nicely. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

After some more googling I think I figured it out. If I change:

```
print(row)
```

to

```
print(row[0])
```

It actually works. I guess this is because row is a tuple and this is way to unpack the tuple correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz

title ='The Title'
tz = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
timestamp = tz.localize(datetime(2015, 05, 20, 13, 56, 02), is_dst=None)

query = "insert into articles values (%s, %s)"
print cursor.mogrify(query, (title, timestamp))
cursor.execute(query, (title, timestamp))
conn.commit()

query = "select * from articles"
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()[0]
print rs[0], rs[1]
print type(rs[1])
```

Output:

```
insert into articles values ('The Title', '2015-05-20T13:56:02-07:00'::timestamptz)
The Title 2015-05-20 17:56:02-03:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```